#  Problem with IF statement in mako template

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I have mako template where i check conditions from a simple dict in for loop, like:

```
% for el in seq:
    % if el["attr"] == 1:
        ...
     elif:
        ....
     else:
        .....
     % endif
```

And if i want add another IF statement in this loop, like:

```
 %if el["attr1"] == 1:
       ....
 %endif
```

I have error: "SyntaxException: Keyword 'endif' doesn't match keyword 'for' in file"
Its possible two or more IF statements in one FOR loop ?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses tags, there is no need to include the subject in the title.

Comment: Next IF statement place between <p> tags, all work great without tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing the %endfor and the % from elif and else statements:

```
%for el in seq:
    %if foo:
        pass
    %elif bar:
        pass
    %else:
        pass
    %endif
%endfor
```